# Fast enumeration on an NSIndexSet

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsindexset

Can you fast enumerate a `NSIndexSet`? if not, what's the best way to enumerate the items in the set?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Fast enumeration must yield objects; since an NSIndexSet contains scalar numbers (`NSUInteger`s), not objects, no, you cannot fast-enumerate an index set.

Hypothetically, it could box them up into NSNumbers, but then it wouldn't be very fast.

Comment: I don't mind the performance hit, but you'd have to slow enumerate before you fast enumerate, right?

Comment: With tagged pointers (on 64-bit platforms since OS X 10.7 and iOS 5), `NSIndexSet` fast enumeration ought to be pretty fast.

Answer (score 149):

In OS X 10.6+ and iOS SDK 4.0+, you can use the `-enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:` message:

```
NSIndexSet *idxSet = ...

[idxSet enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  //... do something with idx
  // *stop = YES; to stop iteration early
}];
```

Comment: Change NSInteger to NSUInteger

Comment: This is the actual answer, can asker change?

Comment: Worth noting that this is also available in iOS SDK 4.0+

Answer (score 22):

A while loop should do the trick. It increments the index after you use the previous index.

```
/*int (as commented, unreliable across different platforms)*/
NSUInteger currentIndex = [someIndexSet firstIndex];
while (currentIndex != NSNotFound)
{
    //use the currentIndex

    //increment
    currentIndex = [someIndexSet indexGreaterThanIndex: currentIndex];
}
```

Comment: Valid indexes can exceed the range of values representable by `int`, since indexes are unsigned. Further, when targeting a 64-bit platform or building with `NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64` defined, the index is a 64-bit value. Use `NSUInteger` instead of `int` in order to match the type stored by `NSIndexSet` under all platforms.

Comment: @Jeremy W. Sherman: actually the indexes are effectively limited to those values that can be represented by a **positive** `NSInteger` because the "not found" return value is `NSNotFound` which is the same as `NSIntegerMax`

Comment: @Evan: this example is still wrong.  The comparison in the while loop needs to be against `NSNotFound` *not* -1.

Comment: @Evan: Interesting.  I was using the Apple developer documentation as a reference.  It seems a little experimentation is needed...  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSIndexSet

Comment: @Evan Mulawski: Just verified that the Apple documentation is correct.  `-indexGreaterThanIndex:` does return NSNotFound, not -1.  The issue in the discussion occurs because he like you was using the wrong return type.

Comment: @JeremyP Wow, I never before noticed that using a signed `NSNotFound` halves the range of index values `NSUInteger` could represent if `NSNotFound` were instead `NSUIntegerMax`. I suppose `NSNotFound` is `NSIntegerMax` so as to agree with `kCFNotFound`; the `CFIndex` type used by CF collections is a signed long. @EveryoneElse Even with indices capped at `NSNotFound` (`NSIntegerMax`), `int` is still the wrong choice to store an index, because the range of `NSInteger` exceeds the range of `int` in 64-bit builds and builds with `NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64` defined.

Answer (score 11):

Short answer:  no.  `NSIndexSet` does not conform to the [`<NSFastEnumeration>` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSFastEnumeration_protocol/Reference/NSFastEnumeration.html).

Comment: what about enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {} --- is this not fast enumeration?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you have an `NSTableView` instance (let's call it `*tableView`), you can delete multiple selected rows from the datasource (uhm.. `*myMutableArrayDataSource`), using:

```
[myMutableArrayDataSource removeObjectsAtIndexes:[tableView selectedRowIndexes]];
```

`[tableView selectedRowIndexes]` returns an `NSIndexSet`.
No need to start enumerating over the indexes in the `NSIndexSet` yourself.

Comment: This isn't actually answering the question, but rather saying "maybe you didn't need to ask that question to start with. What do you want this fast enumeration for?"

Answer (score 1):

These answers are no longer true for IndexSet in **Swift 5**. You can perfectly get something like:

```
let selectedRows:IndexSet = table.selectedRowIndexes
```

and then enumerate the indices like this:

```
for index in selectedRows {
   // your code here.
}
```