# Looping using NSRange

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsrange

I'm trying to use `NSRange` to hold a range of years, such as

```
NSRange years = NSMakeRange(2011, 5);
```

I know `NSRange` is used mostly for filtering, however I want to loop over the elements in the range. Is that possible without converting the `NSRange` into a `NSArray`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It kind of sounds like you're expecting `NSRange` to be like a Python `range` object. It's not; [`NSRange`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW23) is simply a struct

```
typedef struct _NSRange {
       NSUInteger location;
       NSUInteger length;
} NSRange;
```

not an object. Once you've created one, you can use its members in a plain old `for` loop:

```
NSUInteger year;
for(year = years.location; year < NSMaxRange(years); year++ ){
    // Do your thing.
}
```

(Still working on the assumption that you're thinking about Python.) There's syntax in ObjC called [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html) for iterating over the contents of an `NSArray` that is pleasantly similar to a Python `for` loop, but since literal and primitive numbers can't be put into an `NSArray`, you can't go directly from an `NSRange` to a Cocoa array.

A category could make that easier, though:

```
@implementation NSArray (WSSRangeArray)

+ (id)WSSArrayWithNumbersInRange:(NSRange)range
{
    NSMutableArray * arr = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSUInteger i;
    for( i = range.location; i < NSMaxRange(range); i++ ){
        [arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:i]];
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Then you can create an array and use fast enumeration:

```
NSArray * years = [NSArray WSSArrayWithNumbersInRange:NSMakeRange(2011, 5)];
for( NSNumber * yearNum in years ){
    NSUInteger year = [yearNum unsignedIntegerValue];
    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: thanks, too bad there's no support for fast enumeration for NSRange. could save me some time and code lines

Comment: @manroe: I appreciate your correction of my coding error, but the big "EDIT:" block was inappropriate; it could have been a comment, the edit summary, or really just left out altogether.

Answer (score 6):

Remember that a NSRange is a structure holding two integers, representing the start and length of the range. You can easily loop over all of the contained integers using a for loop.

```
NSRange years = NSMakeRange(2011, 5);
NSUInteger year;
for(year = years.location; year < years.location + years.length; ++year) {
    // Use the year variable here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of an old question, but an alternative to using an `NSArray` would be to create an `NSIndexSet` with the desired range (using `indexWithIndexesInRange:` or `initWithIndexesInRange:`) and then using block enumeration as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4209289/138772. (Seemed relevant as I was just checking on this myself.)

Answer (score 0):

My alternate solution for this, was to define a macro just to make shorthand quicker.

```
#define NSRangeEnumerate(i, range)    for(i = range.location; i < NSMaxRange(range); ++i)
```

To call it you do:

```
NSArray *array = @[]; // must contain at least the following range...
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(2011, 5);
NSUInteger i;
NSRangeEnumerate(i, range) {
    id item = array[i];
    // do your thing
}
```

personally I am still trying to figure out how I can write the macro so I can just call it like:

```
NSRangeEnumerate(NSUInteger i, range) {

}
```

which is not supported just yet... hope that helps or makes typing your program quicker