# What is the most efficient way to generate a sequence of NSNumbers?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsnumber

It's a fairly simple builtin in python for example:  `x = range(0,100)`
How can I accomplish the same feat using objective-c methods? Surely there is something better than a NSMutableArray and a for-loop:

```
NSMutableArray *x = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];
for(int n=0; n<100; n++) {
    [x addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:n]];
}
```

Yes, I am aware that doing this is most likely not what I *actually* want to do (ex: `xrange` in python), but humor my curiosity please. =)

**Clarification:** I would like a NSArray containing a sequence of NSNumbers, so that the array could be further processed for example by shuffling elements or sorting by an external metric.

Comment: This has also been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445565/how-to-convert-a-range-to-nsarray-in-objective-c/9445843#9445843

Comment: And definitely check @Monolo answer. It is exactly the kind of dynamic solution you can do in ObjC.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320987/looping-using-nsrange/8321037#8321037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want such an array, you might want to do your own specific subclass of NSArray.

A very basic implementation example would look like:

```
@interface MyRangeArray : NSArray
{
@private
    NSRange myRange;
}

+ (id)arrayWithRange:(NSRange)aRange;
- (id)initWithRange:(NSRange)aRange;

@end

@implementation MyRangeArray

+ (id)arrayWithRange:(NSRange)aRange
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithRange:aRange] autorelease];
}

- (id)initWithRange:(NSRange)aRange
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // TODO: verify aRange limits here
        myRange = aRange;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSUInteger)count
{
    return myRange.length;
}

- (id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    // TODO: add range check here
    return [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(range.location + index)];
}

@end
```

After that, you can override some other NSArray methods to make your class more efficient.

Comment: Note that with some more work, you can make this class extremely efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 100);
```

You can iterate this range by:

```
NSUInteger loc;
for(loc = range.location; loc < range.length; loc++)
{ 
}
```

Comment: I guess I'll clarify my question, I want an NSArray containing all the elements. NSRange doesn't seem to give any utility over a basic for loop for this.