# iOS - Initializing an NSArray with a sequence of numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm looking to do something in Objective C equivalent to the following MATLAB command:

```
A=4:7;
```

In this case, the variable A then becomes an array with elements [4 5 6 7].

Is there any shorthand way to set an NSArray with a sequence of numbers like this in Objective C?  Thanks for reading!

Comment: possible duplicate of [looping using NSRange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320987/looping-using-nsrange)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert a range to NSArray in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445565/how-to-convert-a-range-to-nsarray-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies everyone.  So far, I'm just using a loop:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    int value=i+4;
    [mutableArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value]];
}
NSArray *finalArray=[NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];
```

It doesn't appear that using NSIndexSet does the same thing (Thanks, Martin R and BergQuester), but if anyone has a more efficient way to do this, I'd definitely be interested.

Answer (score 4):

Use a NSIndexSet as the object in the array - you can then use:

```
[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(4, 4)];
```

Answer (score 1):

i think simplest way to use for loop in your case.

Answer (score 1):

use NSIndexSet object:

```
NSArray *seqArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(4, 3)], nil];
```

ADDED: or in newer xcodes:

```
NSArray *seqArray = @[[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(4, 3)]];
```

Comment: That creates an array containing exactly one element (the index set) and not an array containing the elements 4,5,6,7.

Comment: Martin is correct. I don't think this is what the question is asking for.