# How to add 1 through a number to a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, ipad

How do you add every number between 1 and a changing number to a NSMutableArray (so that it can be shown in a UITableView)?

For example, if the changing number at the moment is 8, then the array should contain: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8`. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to use an array for that?

Comment: @CarlNorum I'm creating an app for my school newspaper, and need the array to allow people to choose a page number they want to flip to. The size of the newspaper is not always guaranteed, though, which is why I need this.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320987/looping-using-nsrange/8321037#8321037

Comment: I understand why you want a table view with a list of numbers in it.  I don't understand why you need an array for that.

Comment: @JackHumphries look at lulius's comment.. this is the best approach I would say.. without using much memory.

Comment: @JackHumphries: you may have accepted a different answer, and the answer fits exactly your question, but to save memory & add performance, please consider my answer as well - you really dont need to make an array for this :)

Comment: @SebastianFlückiger Thanks for your answer. I gave you an up vote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
int number = 8;
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:number];
for (int i=1; i<=number; i++) {
    [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]]
}
NSLog(@"%@", [mutableArray description]);
```

Answer (score 4):

i recommend the following approach (not needing an array). for your a numbers

```
-numberOfSectionsInTableView..{
    return 1;
}

-numberOfRowsInSection..{
    return a;
}

-cellForRowAtIndexPath..{
    UITableViewCell* cell = ...
    UILabel *label = ...
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row+1]];
    [cell addSubView:label];
    return cell;
}
```

resulting in a table with 1 section, a rows, and each row will have a label with the 
number 1 to a on it.

sebastian

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSMutableArray*)arrayForNumber:(int)number {
    NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }

    return array;
}
```