# Continuous numbers in Objective-C array like range() in Python

Tags: python, objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa

Python can make a list with continuous numbers like this:

```
numbers=range(1,10); // >> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

How to implement this in Objective-c?

Comment: what purpose do you need this range for?

Comment: @holex Just need an array with continuous numbers,I do not want to init it with a loop.

Comment: then it is very hard to tell what solution is the best for you. the generic solution is to init an array with a loop and you can use that array for everything but there would be some other and more elegant tricks for special cases but we don't know anything about your final goal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [looping using NSRange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320987/looping-using-nsrange), [Convert a range to NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445565/how-to-convert-a-range-to-nsarray-in-objective-c?lq=1), [Add 1 through a number to NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058007/how-to-add-1-through-a-number-to-a-nsmutablearray?lq=1), [A list or array of sequential integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693985/a-list-or-array-of-sequential-integers?lq=1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reading your statement *"
    Just need an array with continuous numbers,I do not want to init it with a loop"* lets me ask: what is more important for you: to have an *`array`* or to have "*something*" that represents a continuous range of (natural) numbers. Have a look at `NSIndexSet` It may come close to what you want. You initialize it with

```
[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1,9)];
```

Iterating over this set is as simple as iterating over an array and does not need NSNumbers.

Answer (score 6):

Objective-C (or Foundation actually) does not have a special function for this. You could use:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i=1; i<10; i++) {
    [array addObject:@(i)]; // @() is the modern objective-c syntax, to box the value into an NSNumber.
}
// If you need an immutable array, add NSArray *immutableArray = [array copy];
```

If you want to use it more often you could optionally put it in an [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html).

Comment: Yes I used this way also,I just want to find a little simple way.

Comment: As I put in the edit, if you use it more often you can create a category (link in answer) that would allow you to do: [NSArray arrayWithNumbersFrom:1 to:10];

Comment: @Veelian Why not wrap the above code up in a method and put it in a category on `NSArray`?  The signature would be something like `-(NSArray*) arrayWithRangeFrom: (int) start to: (int) stop step: (int) step;`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NSRange` .

```
NSRange numbers = NSMakeRange(1, 10);
```

*NSRange* is simply a struct and **not** like a Python *range* object.

```
typedef struct _NSRange {
       NSUInteger location;
       NSUInteger length;
} NSRange;
```

So you have to use *for* loop to access its members.

```
NSUInteger num;
for(num = 1; num <= maxValue; num++ ){
    // Do Something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass NSArray with a class for ranges. Subclassing NSArray is quite simple:

- you need a suitable initialization method, which calls `[super init]`; and
- you need to override `count` and `objectAtIndex:`

You can do more, but you don't need to. Here is a sketch missing some checking code:

```
@interface RangeArray : NSArray

- (id) initWithRangeFrom:(NSInteger)firstValue to:(NSInteger)lastValue;

@end

@implementation RangeArray
{
    NSInteger start, count;
}

- (id) initWithRangeFrom:(NSInteger)firstValue to:(NSInteger)lastValue
{
    // should check firstValue < lastValue and take appropriate action if not
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        start = firstValue;
        count = lastValue - firstValue + 1;
    }
    return self;
}

// to subclass NSArray only need to override count & objectAtIndex:

- (NSUInteger) count
{
    return count;
}

- (id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (index >= count)
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSRangeException reason:@"Index out of bounds" userInfo:nil];
    else
        return [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(start + index)];
}

@end
```

You can use this as follows:

```
NSArray *myRange = [[RangeArray alloc] initWithRangeFrom:1 to:10];
```

If you `copy` a `RangeArray` it will become a normal array of `NSNumber` objects, but you can avoid if you wish by implementing the `NSCopying` protocol methods.