# How can I convert an NSRange to a delimited string of its values?

Tags: objective-c, loops, csv, nsstring, nsrange

Given an NSRange, such as:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(1, 22);
```

What's the best way to convert it to a comma-separated string of its values?

```
@"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22"
```

The best I could come up with was to iterate over the range and insert its values into an NSArray, and then call `-componentsJoinedByString:` on the array. But that seems pretty wasteful, not to mention inelegant. Is there no better way?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. This is not python. ;)

Comment: @dasdom So you know where I'm coming from, eh? I'm used to it being easy: `perl -E 'say join ",", 1..22'`

Comment: `NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];for (int i = range.location; i < range.length; i ++){[string appendFormat:"%d,",i]};[string deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(string.length-1,1)];` ? That's the kind of thing your looking for?

Comment: @Larme Yeah, as in J2thC's answer. So ugly, though.

Comment: Well, usually that's not the role of a `NSRange`, I only used it in NSString actually, and we don't often use that (well, I didn't see a use)... If there is some logic, why not create it on the fly? You want element 3? `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 3+offsetStart]`.

Comment: Similar/related: [Looping using NSRange](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8320987) (note wistful mention of Python there too!)

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableString *string=[@"" mutableCopy];
for (int i = range.location; i<range.length-1; i++){
   [string appendFormat:@"%d,", i];
}
[string appendString@"%d", range.length-1];
```

If you want to hide the code, you can turn it into a function that would take the range and turn it into a string, that way this is hidden from your code. Or maybe turn it into a `NSString` class method, something like

```
[NSString stringWithRangeValues:range];
```

That would be like:

```
+ (NSString *)stringWithRangeValues:(NSRange)range{
        NSMutableString *string=[@"" mutableCopy];
        for (int i = range.location; i<range.lenght-1; i++){
           [string appendFormat:@"%d,", i];
        }
        [string appendString@"%d", range.length-1];
        return [NSString stringWithString:string];
```

}

Comment: yea i noticed it and removed it.

Answer (score 2):

My version using an array:

```
NSMutableArray *vals = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:range.length];
for (NSUInteger i = range.location; i < range.length; i++){
    [vals addObject:@(i)];
}
NSString *string = [vals componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSIndexSet with `indexSetWithIndexesInRange:` to generate a list of values, and then iterate through them with `enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:`. E.g.

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
NSMutableArray *indices = [NSMutableArray array];
[indexSet enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
    [indices addObject:@(i)];
}];
NSString *string = [indices componentsJoinedByString:","];
```

Comment: Maybe I should have asked for increasingly complex ways to solve this problem. ;-P

Comment: Hah. It was all I could think of :) I thought there might have been a way to convert an NSIndexSet to an NSArray populated with the indices of the elements, but alas, no dice. NSIndexSet is basically the higher-level version of an NSRange so my answer doesn't quite have too much of a benefit, unless you want to stay away from using NSRange directly.