# Find all indexes of a string inside NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have `NSMutableArray` with data like: "John","Phillip","John","Andrea". I have also a String "John". I need to find that string in `NSMutableArray` and define which index is to show other data in other arrays. In my case index is 0 and 2.

This show only first

```
NSInteger index = [array indexOfObject:String];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSArray` provides a method that produces a set of indexes based on a condition that you supply:

```
NSIndexSet *allPositions = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:
    ^BOOL (id str, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
        return [str isEqualToString:String];
    }];
```

This produces `NSIndexSet` which has all indexes of interest - in your case, it would have 0 and 2.

Comment: How should I use this allPostions in [data objectAtIndex:allPositions] ? I need integer number to show data.

Comment: @WildWorld Depending on your situation, you could either [enumerate your index set using a block](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4209289/335858), or transform it into an array of `NSInteger`s using `getIndexes:maxCount:inIndexRange:` method.